# Symfony4 pluralization on translation not working

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, icu

Pluralization is working partially in Symfony4.3 when I use the new ICU Format for messages.

Expected behaviour: `One item found`

Current behaviour: `{1, plural, =0 {No items found.} one {One item found.} other {# items found.} }`

Translation file works for other translations, so configuration I think is right. In translations/messagges.en.yaml

```
msg:
    photos:
        uploaded: >
            {photos, plural,
                =0 {No items found.}
                one {One item found.}
                other {# items found.}
            }
```

And in the template there is the following line:

```
{{ 'msg.photos.uploaded'|trans({'photos': 1}) }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe, for the ICU message format to work, the filename must be correct (more precisely, the domain must have `+intl-icu` appended):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#using-the-icu-message-format

in your case, the filename should be: `translations/messages+intl-icu.en.yaml` according to the source above.

Comment: Great, it works! I didn't realize file name was different. Also, I had to install symfony/polyfill-intl-messageformatter package as I am using symfony server on dev. Thank you!